# Multivalued attributes in Dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

With Dexterity I can create a model of contact cards having an email attribute.

```
class IContact(form.Schema):
    email = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Email"),
            description=_(u"Contact email"),
        )
```

How can I modify this schema to have multiple emails for each contact? I know that it is possible to add emails as a nested content type. Thus, my question is if Dexterity supports multivalued attributes inside content types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it does, wrap the email `TextLine` in a `schema.List`:

```
schema.List(
        title=u"Email adresses",
        required=False,
        value_type=schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Email"),
        ))
```

Comment: How can I use a compound attribute in a List? Suppose that I need to ask for a list of points, each one composed by two attributes, x and y.

Comment: @DanielHernández: Define the entries as a interface itself, then use the interface as a `value_type`, IIRC.